# C#/SQL table doesn't show new entry

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio

I have a comboBox that inserts new data fine. But won't update when I select certain existing data. I tried to write a crazy insertUpdate method but no luck. Any help will be appreciated. Here is my C#:

```
if (updateDataButton.Checked == true)
                    {
                        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection objCon2 =
                        new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=EmployeeProjects; Integrated Security=TRUE"))
                        {

                            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand objCmd2 =
                                new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("pUpdEmployeeProjectHours", objCon2))
                            {
                                objCmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                                objCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", EmployeeNameBox.Text);

                                insertUpdates();

                                objCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", ProjectNameBox.Text);
                                objCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Parse(DateTimeBox.Text));
                                objCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hours", HoursBox.Text);

                                try
                                {

                                    objCon2.Open();

                                    objCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da2
                   = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("Select * From EmployeeProjectHours", objCon2);



                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    throw;
                                }
                                finally
                                {

                                    objCon2.Close();

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
    private void insertUpdates()
    {//.ToString()
        if (EmployeeNameBox.SelectedText == "Bob Smith")
        {
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection objCon =
               new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=EmployeeProjects; Integrated Security=TRUE"))
            {

                using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand objCmd =
                    new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("pUpdEmployeeNames", objCon))
                {

                    objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", 1);
                    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", EmployeeNameBox.Text);



                    try
                    {
                        objCon.Open();
                        objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da4
                = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("Select * From EmployeeProjectHours", objCon);



                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                    finally
                    {

                        objCon.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        else
            if (EmployeeNameBox.SelectedText == "Sue Jones")
            {
                {
                    using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection objCon2 =
                      new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=EmployeeProjects; Integrated Security=TRUE"))
                    {

                        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand objCmd2 =
                            new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("pUpdEmployeeNames", objCon2))
                        {

                            objCmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                                objCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", 2);
                                objCmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", EmployeeNameBox.Text);



                            try
                            {
                                objCon2.Open();
                                objCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da5
                        = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("Select * From EmployeeProjectHours", objCon2);



                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                throw;
                            }
                            finally
                            {

                                objCon2.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Here is the query;

```
Set NoCount On -- Turns off the annoying "One Row affected" messages 
-- Note: Do not place the Set NoCount On option inside a Stored Procedure, since it 
-- will send a false error to an ADO.NET DataAdpater object.

-- 1) Make the databse
USE [master]
GO
If Exists(Select Name from master.Sys.databases where name = 'EmployeeProjects')
 Begin 
  ALTER DATABASE [EmployeeProjects] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 
    Drop Database[EmployeeProjects]
 End 
GO

CREATE DATABASE [EmployeeProjects]
GO

USE [EmployeeProjects]
GO

-- 2) Make the tables
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees]
(
    [EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
    [EmployeeName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Projects]
(
    [ProjectId] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [ProjectName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ProjectDescription] [varchar](5000) NOT NULL,
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeProjectHours]
(
    [EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Hours] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeeProjectHours] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        ([EmployeeId] ASC,[ProjectId] ASC,[Date] ASC)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ThisYearsDates]
(
    [DateId] [int] Identity NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [DateName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ValidHourEntries]
(
    [TimePeriodId] [int] Identity NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [TimePeriod] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
)
GO

-- 3) Fill the tables with test data
-- Add two test employees
Insert into [dbo].[Employees] Values (1, 'Bob Smith')
Insert into [dbo].[Employees] Values (2, 'Sue Jones')
GO
-- Add two test Projects
Insert into [dbo].[Projects] Values (100, 'Accounting DB Upgrade', 'Upgrade the Accounting Database to our new SQL 2008 Server')
Insert into [dbo].[Projects] Values (101, 'Accounting Application Upgrade', 'Modify our existing Accounting Application to connect to the new upgraded server')
GO
-- Add four test Employee Project Hours
Insert into [dbo].[EmployeeProjectHours] Values (1,100,'1/1/' + Cast(Year(Getdate()) as varchar(4)), 6)
Insert into [dbo].[EmployeeProjectHours] Values (1,100,'1/2/' + Cast(Year(Getdate()) as varchar(4)), 4)
Insert into [dbo].[EmployeeProjectHours] Values (2,101,'1/1/' + Cast(Year(Getdate()) as varchar(4)), 5.5)
Insert into [dbo].[EmployeeProjectHours] Values (2,101,'1/2/' + Cast(Year(Getdate()) as varchar(4)), 6)
GO

-- Add This years dates
Declare @DateId int = 1
Declare @Date datetime = '1/1/' + Cast(Year(GetDate()) as Varchar(4));
While (Year(@Date) < (Year(GetDate()) + 1))
    Begin
        Insert into [dbo].[ThisYearsDates]Values(Convert(varchar(50), @Date, 101) )
        Set @DateId = @DateId + 1
        Set @Date = DateAdd(dd, 1, @Date)
    End
GO

-- Add Valid Hourly Entries
Declare @TimePeriod decimal(18,2) = 0
While ( @TimePeriod <= 24)
    Begin 
        Insert into [ValidHourEntries]( TimePeriod) Values (@TimePeriod)
        Set @TimePeriod = @TimePeriod + .25 
    End
Go

-- 4) Review everything you have so far
Select * From [dbo].[Employees]
Select * From [dbo].[Projects]
Select * From [dbo].[EmployeeProjectHours]
Select * From [dbo].[ThisYearsDates]
Select * From [dbo].[ValidHourEntries]
GO


-- 5) Create Select Sprocs for Tables
Create Proc pSelEmployeeNames
  AS
  Begin
    Declare @RC int = 0
    Begin Try
        Select 
            EmployeeName 
        From [dbo].[Employees]
        Set @RC = 100 -- Indicates Success  
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Set @RC = -100 --Indicates Error
    End Catch   
    Return @RC
  End   
GO

Create Proc pSelProjectNames
  AS
  Begin
    Declare @RC int = 0
    Begin Try
        Select 
            ProjectName 
        From [dbo].[Projects]
        Set @RC = 100 -- Indicates Success          
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Set @RC = -100 --Indicates Error
    End Catch   
    Return @RC
  End   
GO

Create Proc pSelEmployeeProjectHours
  AS
  Begin
    Declare @RC int = 0
    Begin Try  
        SELECT 
            dbo.EmployeeProjectHours.Date, 
            dbo.Employees.EmployeeName, 
            dbo.Projects.ProjectName, 
            dbo.EmployeeProjectHours.Hours
        FROM  dbo.EmployeeProjectHours 
        INNER JOIN dbo.Employees 
            ON dbo.EmployeeProjectHours.EmployeeId = dbo.Employees.EmployeeId 
        INNER JOIN dbo.Projects 
            ON dbo.EmployeeProjectHours.ProjectId = dbo.Projects.ProjectId
    Set @RC = 100 -- Indicates Success          
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Set @RC = -100 --Indicates Error
    End Catch   
    Return @RC
  End       
GO

Create Proc pSelThisYearsDates
  AS
  Begin
    Declare @RC int = 0
    Begin Try
      SELECT 
       [DateId]
      ,[DateName] 
      FROM [ThisYearsDates]
        Set @RC = 100 -- Indicates Success          
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Set @RC = -100 --Indicates Error
    End Catch   
    Return @RC
  End   
GO


Create Proc pSelValidHours
  AS
  Begin
    Declare @RC int = 0
    Begin Try
        Select
        TimePeriodId,
        TimePeriod
        From ValidHourEntries
        Set @RC = 100 -- Indicates Success          
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Set @RC = -100 --Indicates Error
    End Catch   
    Return @RC
  End   
GO


    -- 5a) Review everything you have so far
Exec pSelEmployeeNames
Exec pSelProjectNames
Exec pSelEmployeeProjectHours
Exec pSelThisYearsDates
Exec pSelValidHours
GO


-- 6) Insert Sprocs
Create Proc pInsEmployeeNames
( @EmployeeId int, @EmployeeName varchar(100))
  AS
  Begin
    Declare @RC int = 0
    Begin Try  
      Begin Transaction  
        Insert into [dbo].[Employees] Values (@EmployeeId,@EmployeeName)
      Commit Transaction
    Set @RC = 100 -- Indicates Success          
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Set @RC = -100 --Indicates Error
        Rollback Transaction            
    End Catch   
    Return @RC
  End   
GO

Create Proc pInsProjectNames
( @ProjectId int, @ProjectName varchar(100), @ProjectDescription varchar(5000))
  AS
  Begin
    Declare @RC int = 0
    Begin Try  
      Begin Transaction    
        Insert into [dbo].[Projects] Values (@ProjectId, @ProjectName, @ProjectDescription)
      Commit Transaction
    Set @RC = 100 -- Indicates Success          
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Set @RC = -100 --Indicates Error
        Rollback Transaction            
    End Catch   
    Return @RC
  End   
GO

Create Proc pInsEmployeeProjectHours
( @EmployeeName varchar(100), @ProjectName varchar(100), @Date datetime, @Hours decimal(18,2))
  AS
  Begin
    Declare @RC int = 0, @EmployeeId Int = 0, @ProjectId int = 0    
    Begin Try  
        -- Look up the IDs

        Select @EmployeeId = EmployeeId From dbo.Employees Where EmployeeName = @EmployeeName
        Select @ProjectId = ProjectId From dbo.Projects Where ProjectName = @ProjectName    
      Begin Transaction         
        Insert into [dbo].[EmployeeProjectHours] Values(@EmployeeId, @ProjectId, @Date, @Hours) 
      Commit Transaction        
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Set @RC = -100 --Indicates Error
        Rollback Transaction        
    End Catch   
    Return @RC
  End   
GO

    -- 6a) Review everything you have so far
Exec pInsEmployeeNames @EmployeeId = 3 , @EmployeeName = 'Test User' 
Exec pInsProjectNames @ProjectId = 103, @ProjectName = 'Test Project' , @ProjectDescription = 'Test Desc'
Exec pInsEmployeeProjectHours @EmployeeName = 'Test User', @ProjectName = 'Test Project', @Date = '1/1/2011', @Hours = 1
GO

Exec pSelEmployeeNames
Exec pSelProjectNames
Exec pSelEmployeeProjectHours
GO


-- 7) Update Sprocs
Create Proc pUpdEmployeeNames
( @EmployeeId int, @EmployeeName varchar(100))
  AS
  Begin
    Declare @RC int = 0
    Begin Try  
      Begin Transaction  
        Update [dbo].[Employees] 
        Set 
            [EmployeeId] = @EmployeeId, 
            [EmployeeName] = @EmployeeName
        Where 
            [EmployeeId] = @EmployeeId 
            OR 
            [EmployeeName] = @EmployeeName
      Commit Transaction
    Set @RC = 100 -- Indicates Success          
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Set @RC = -100 --Indicates Error
        Rollback Transaction
    End Catch   
    Return @RC
  End   
GO

Create Proc pUpdProjectNames
( @ProjectId int, @ProjectName varchar(100),  @ProjectDescription varchar(5000))
  AS
  Begin
    Declare @RC int = 0
    Begin Try  
      Begin Transaction    
        Update [dbo].[Projects]
        Set 
            [ProjectId] = @ProjectId, 
            [ProjectName] = @ProjectName,
            [ProjectDescription] = @ProjectDescription          
        Where 
            [ProjectId] = @ProjectId 
            OR 
            [ProjectName] = @ProjectName
            OR    
            [ProjectDescription] = @ProjectDescription        
      Commit Transaction
    Set @RC = 100 -- Indicates Success          
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Set @RC = -100 --Indicates Error
        Rollback Transaction        
    End Catch   
    Return @RC
  End   
GO

Create Proc pUpdEmployeeProjectHours
( @EmployeeName varchar(100), @ProjectName varchar(100), @Date datetime, @Hours decimal(18,2))
  AS
  Begin
    Declare @RC int = 0, @EmployeeId Int = 0, @ProjectId int = 0   
    Begin Try  
        -- Look up the IDs
        Select @EmployeeId = EmployeeId From dbo.Employees Where EmployeeName = @EmployeeName
        Select @ProjectId = ProjectId From dbo.Projects Where ProjectName = @ProjectName    

      Begin Transaction   
        Update [dbo].[EmployeeProjectHours]
        Set 
            [EmployeeId] = @EmployeeId, 
            [ProjectId] = @ProjectId, 
            [Date] = @Date,
            [Hours]= @Hours             
        Where 
            [EmployeeId] = @EmployeeId 
            AND
            [ProjectId] = @ProjectId 
            AND
            [Date] = @Date
      Commit Transaction        
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Set @RC = -100 --Indicates Error
        Rollback Transaction            
    End Catch   
    Return @RC
  End   
GO

    -- 7a) Review everything you have so far
    Exec pUpdEmployeeNames @EmployeeId = 3 , @EmployeeName = 'Test User 2' 
    Exec pUpdProjectNames @ProjectId = 103, @ProjectName = 'Test Project 2' , @ProjectDescription = 'Test Desc 2'
    Exec pUpdEmployeeProjectHours @EmployeeName = 'Test User 2',@ProjectName = 'Test Project 2' , @Date = '1/1/2011' , @Hours = 10
    GO

    Exec pSelEmployeeNames
    Exec pSelProjectNames
    Exec pSelEmployeeProjectHours
    GO

-- 8) Delete Sprocs
Create Proc pDelEmployeeNames
( @EmployeeId int = -1, @EmployeeName varchar(100) = '')
  AS
  Begin
    Declare @RC int = 0
    Begin Try  
      Begin Transaction  
        Delete From [dbo].[Employees] 
        Where 
            [EmployeeId] = @EmployeeId 
            OR 
            [EmployeeName] = @EmployeeName
      Commit Transaction
    Set @RC = 100 -- Indicates Success          
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Set @RC = -100 --Indicates Error
    End Catch   
    Return @RC
  End   
GO

Create Proc pDelProjectNames
( @ProjectId int = -1, @ProjectName varchar(100) = '',  @ProjectDescription varchar(5000) = '')
  AS
  Begin
    Declare @RC int = 0
    Begin Try  
      Begin Transaction    
        Delete From [dbo].[Projects]
        Where 
            [ProjectId] = @ProjectId 
            OR 
            [ProjectName] = @ProjectName
            OR    
            [ProjectDescription] = @ProjectDescription        
      Commit Transaction
    Set @RC = 100 -- Indicates Success          
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Set @RC = -100 --Indicates Error
    End Catch   
    Return @RC
  End   
GO

Create Proc pDelEmployeeProjectHours
( @EmployeeName varchar(100), @ProjectName varchar(100), @Date datetime )
  AS
  Begin
    Declare @RC int = 0, @EmployeeId Int = 0, @ProjectId int = 0 

     -- Look up the IDs
    Select @EmployeeId = EmployeeId From dbo.Employees Where EmployeeName = @EmployeeName
    Select @ProjectId = ProjectId From dbo.Projects Where ProjectName = @ProjectName    

    Begin Try    
      Begin Transaction     
        Delete From [dbo].[EmployeeProjectHours]
        Where 
            [EmployeeId] = @EmployeeId 
            AND
            [ProjectId] = @ProjectId 
            AND
            [Date] = @Date
      Commit Transaction        
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        Set @RC = -100 --Indicates Error
    End Catch   
    Return @RC
  End   
GO

    -- 8a) Review everything you have so far
    Exec pDelEmployeeNames @EmployeeId = 3 , @EmployeeName = 'Test User 2' 
    Exec pDelProjectNames @ProjectId = 103, @ProjectName = 'Test Project 2' , @ProjectDescription = 'Test Desc 2'
    Exec pDelEmployeeProjectHours @EmployeeName = 'Test User 2' , @ProjectName = 'Test Project 2', @Date = '1/1/2011'
    GO

    Exec pSelEmployeeNames
    Exec pSelProjectNames
    Exec pSelEmployeeProjectHours
    GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the EmployeeId field to Auto Increment. If you need the EmployeeId back, use SCOPE_IDENTITY.

```
CREATE TABLE (
  EmployeeId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
);
```

Comment: @Albendini You rejected my answer, changes your question and code to use my answer, then changed your question. Not cool. Also, you might get help if you posted the error you're getting when updating, just not from me.

Comment: Sorry dude. Not sure how this site works. I thought by accepting your answer that it would end the question. I didn't really understand your answer. And that's probably because I don't know the first thing about c# or sql. Therefore, I was hoping to get instructions that I could code in c# or by changing my comboBox properties. But I' don't have a clue how to add sql code to my c# yet. Sorry again.

Comment: No Problem, the code I gave you is SQL code, like the query you presented for creating your Tables. When you use the keyword IDENTITY for the ID field SQL will automatically insert the EmployeeId field data for you when you add a new Employee record. You'll use this ID to pull data back out.